# Problem with accessing static files when deploying Django API using Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework

I have `schema.yml` documentation in the static folder in my project and during development everything seems to be working properly however after deployment to the `App Engine` I get the error `Not Found /static/schema.yml`. My configuration looks in the way shown below. Do you have any ideas what can be the cause of the problem?

settings.py:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
service: mysite-service

handlers:
- url: /static/
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine Flex for custom environments ignores the [handlers section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml). There are no issues if you add this section to your “app.yaml” but are not used by the environment. The handlers section is for [Google App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref). So, that is the reason why in the App Engine Standard environment works but not in App Engine flex. The only language that supports handlers is [java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) and you can find documentation that says that it is possible to do it.

However, in order to serve static files, you can take a look at [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files) where it includes the necessary steps to configure static files in App Engine Flex.

Comment: So the only solution is to upload static files in the external source like for example Google Cloud Storage and just use configuration like `STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{storage bucket}/static/'`? I would never thought that it is not possible to access and download static files from local system.

Comment: Actually, you can serve files from [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files#serving_files_from), [directly from your app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files#serving_from_your_application) and from a [third-party content delivery network](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files#serving_from_a_third-party_content_delivery_network)